# Installing mfpdev-cli via NPM causes error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, npm-install, mobilefirst-cli

When installing mfpdev-cli via npm I'm receiving the following error:

```
$ npm install -g mfpdev-cli@latest
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-adapter-actions
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-android-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-config
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-preview
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-pull
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-push
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-register
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-webencrypt
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-app-webupdate
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cmd-adapter
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cmd-app
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cmd-config
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cmd-info
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cmd-server
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-cordova-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-errors
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-exec
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-ios-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-browser-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-mbs
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-server-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mdo-windows-support
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/platform-manager
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ibm-strings/-/ibm-strings-0.1.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/mfp-config-xml/-/mfp-config-xml-0.0.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/pluggington/-/pluggington-0.3.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404
```

Any ideas on how to get around this and install the latest version of the MobileFirst CLI?  I'm running npm version 3.10.7 on Mac OS X 10.11.6 and my node version is 4.2.4.

Thanks for your help,

John

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same issue.

I checked my `npm` version and it was `3.10.9`. I downgraded it to `2.14.7`, what has resolved my issues regarding the `404` error.

Answer (score 3):

Source: https://portal2portal.blogspot.in/2017/12/ibm-mobilefirst-8-commanding-cli.html

May 2018,
npm install -g mfpdev-cli is still not working but I have found a way to make it work. **The node version must be 7.3.0 and npm version must be 3.10.10.**

**Steps** : 
 1. Downgrade (or Upgrade) node to 7.3.0. Copy and paste these commands to remove node.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}

$ sudo apt autoremove
```

2. Now install the required version of node(7.3.0) using nvm or n or whatever you like. I have nvm installed so I did it with nvm

```
$ nvm install 7.3.0
```

With this command node and npm will automatically be installed to the required version. Verify npm and node before running the final command:

```
$ npm install -g mfpdev-cli
```

or :

```
$ sudo npm install -g mfpdev-cli
```

In my case it did not work with sudo. But it can work in your case maybe.

The credit goes to the original poster in that link. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there was a change in the most recent version of npm in that only version 3.10.7 causes this issue to appear.  The work-around is to regress your version of npm to 3.10.6.

The MobileFirst development team is working on a fix and I'll update this answer with that information once that occurs.

Please post below if you have any questions about this.

Thanks,

John Gerken

Comment: Just a quick update that an official fix for this issue is still forthcoming.  We expect to release it soon.

Comment: I'm getting this error and my version is 3.10.10 . How can I overcome this? @John